# Service Fabric Reverse Proxy with https

Tags: https, reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

So I try to use the reverse proxy of Azure Service Fabric with https on a standalone cluster but I'm not able to made it happend.

I read many pages of the documentation but I must miss one or I'm not able to understand it.

So what I want is to call the reverse proxy with https (working fine with http) like https://localhost/SFTest/api/weatherforecast but It's wont work. If I use the "direct link" like https://localhost:xxxx/weatherforecast it's work

First I was using the web installer to setup my dev env on my local machine but from what I read if I want to be able to manage cluster settings it was better to switch to the "full mode" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server)

With this I was able to create a cluster by using the config "ClusterConfig.Unsecure.DevCluster.json" but the https was not enabled for the reverse proxy.

The isssue is that I have trouble making the difference between securing a cluster and just enable https on reverse proxy. I don't want to have to use certs to connect to the cluster (like going to https://localhost:19081)

Can someone tell me how to enable the ssl (which config file to edit and what to put in it) to the reverse proxy without having to secure the cluster?

It will be a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

So I manage to found how to do it

In the config of the cluster (ClusterConfig.json) or the template (in my case it was ClusterConfig.Unsecure.DevCluster.json) you have to add this

```
"security": {
         "CertificateInformation": {
             "ReverseProxyCertificate": {
                 "Thumbprint": "[ReplaceByThumbprint]",
                 "ThumbprintSecondary": "[ReplaceByThumbprint]",
                 "X509StoreName": "My"
             }
         }
    }
```

Under the "properties" part